# Rich text editor without execCommand or any other libraries

Tags: rich-text-editor

Is there any way to code a Rich text editor without using execCommand or any other libraries and packages to do only using Vanilla JS

Was searching for a way to do without using execCommand or any other extra libraries for a while but can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I wrote one called [editor2](https://github.com/tonioloewald/editor2) back in 2015 but didn't quite get it ready before I left the job so it didn't make it into production. The open source version is sitting in my github. I have had plans to rewrite it without using jQuery (it's one of the last things I ever did with jQuery) but the need hasn't arisen.

The live demo is [here](https://tonioloewald.github.io/editor2/)

As I say, it's not quite production quality. I'd call this a late alpha / proof of concept. The demo document I used was the US Constitution (abbreviated here just to keep the demo light—performance is not an issue).

Back then I had implemented a very full-featured in-browser WYSIWYG editor that was supposed to be open-sourced but never was. (It featured a lot of the functionality of Microsoft Word, including per-user change-tracking.)

It was, however, based on document.execCommand which I knew well enough to despise. Hence editor2.

Given that document.execCommand is now deprecated, I may go and rebuild editor2 as a web-component with no dependencies (except xinjs for its base Component class which I know really well).